# Validate drop-down and listbox at client side in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to validate drop down and List box at client side.

//model

```
 public class NewStreamViewModel
    {
        public NewStreamViewModel()
        {
            this.Subjects = new List<SelectListItem>();
            this.Languages = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }

        [Display(Name = "Language")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is Required")]
        public int LanguageId {get;set;}




        [Display(Name = "Subject")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is Required")]
        public int[] SubjectIds {get;set;}

        public List<SelectListItem> Languages {get;set;}
       public List<SelectListItem> Subjects {get;set;}

    }
```

//View

```
<div id="tab1">
    <table style="background: none; width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Language
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.LanguageId,Model.Languages)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.LanguageId)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Stream
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StreamId, Model.Streams)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subjects
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SubjectIds, Model.Subjects, 
                    new { Style = "width:300px;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.SubjectIds)
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="button" id="addspan">
</div>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#addspan').click(function () {
            var $step = $('#tab1');
            var validator = $("form").validate(); // obtain validator
            var anyError = false;
            $step.find('select').each(function () {
                // validate every input element inside this step
                if (!validator.element(this)) { 
                    anyError = true;
                }
            })
</script>
```

I have use unobtrusive validation but still it's not working for me,
how i can validate drop down and List box at client side?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that the script tag for jquery is not ok. Change it like the tags below it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: i have checked it, it's working

Comment: Have you enabled the unobtrusive JS in config, or from code?

Answer (score 0):

use hack to apply a validation on dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DetailsData.TypeSelected, new SelectList(Model.Types, "Value", "Key"), "- Choose Offer Type -", new { @class = "" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DetailsData.TypeSelected, new { @style = "visibility : hidden" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DetailsData.TypeSelected, null, new { @class ="validation_arrow shift_arrow" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DetailsData.TypeSelected)
```

Comment: if DetailsData.TypeSelected = 0  means my i want to also put validation on index also in that case i am not able to use  this scenario

Comment: mainly the validation control by the **hidden** textbox check this in jquery valid form.

Answer (score 0):

You ca perform somthing like this:

```
$('#addspan').click(function () {
        if($('#dropDownID1').val() != 0 && $('#dropDownID2').val() != 0)
//do something
else alert("Please complete required fileds");
        })
```